# how can I access HTTP GET variables in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to access the HTTP GET variables in a Google Apps Script (Like PHPs $_GET). 
I tried several techniques:

- Plain java script (window.location), which obviously is not supported
- Googles own Service through SitesApp.getActivePage().getUrl(). Gives
  me the URL, but without the variable string. On second thought this
  might make  sense.
- e.parameter.[key] This gives me the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined.

I'd really appreciate some pointers or a working example, thanks.

As per the comment from Srik I tried the following:

```
function doGet(e) { 
    UserProperties.setProperty("bottleid", e.parameter.id);
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('showbottledata').evaluate();
}
```

Which gives me the mentioned 
TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined. (line 2)
error.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define your doGet in such a way that it accepts URL parameters

```
function doGet(e) {
   ....
}
```

When you call your URL using URL parameters, say parm1=val1, use

```
var parm1 = e.parameter.parm1 ;
```

Comment: ok, thanks. I tried the following: `function doGet(e) {
  UserProperties.setProperty("bottleid", e.parameters.id);
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('showbottledata').evaluate();
}`, which gives me the mentioned "cannot read property from undefined" error.

Comment: Can you give the URL you used to call this script ? I think you may have to use the old URL format as there was a bug opened. I'm not sure of the status of the bug though.